# New in swiftmailer

Tags: php, html, email, swiftmailer

I am new in swiftmailer, I am having this kind of error;

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Swift_Mime_Headers_DateHeader in /home/hosting/public_html/lib/classes/Swift/Mime/Headers/DateHeader.php on line 17

I don't know what to do, please help

My code is this:

```
 require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';

    // Create the Transport
    $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.example.org', 25)
      ->setUsername('your username')
      ->setPassword('your password')
      ;

    /*
    You could alternatively use a different transport such as Sendmail or Mail:

    // Sendmail
    $transport = Swift_SendmailTransport::newInstance('/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs');

    // Mail
    $transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();
    */

    // Create the Mailer using your created Transport
    $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

    // Create a message
    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Wonderful Subject')
      ->setFrom(array('john@doe.com' => 'John Doe'))
      ->setTo(array('receiver@domain.org', 'other@domain.org' => 'A name'))
      ->setBody('Here is the message itself')
      ;

    // Send the message
    $result = $mailer->send($message);
```